# Decimal precision in an EXTJS grid Row Editing Plugin

Tags: grid, extjs4

I am using Extjs 4.2.1 with RowEditing plugin. I need to change the decimal separator from "." for ",". I used this code in the render event Viewport

```
 Ext.util.Format.thousandSeparator = '.'; 
 Ext.util.Format.decimalSeparator = ',';
```

Still in the grid to edit the column with the decimal separator NumberField editor continues with "." instead of the ",".

How to change decimal separator in RowEditing plugin?
I thought something like this link 
[Decimal precision in an EXTJS grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133101/decimal-precision-in-an-extjs-grid)

Follow the column definition:

```
           {
            text : "Valor unit&aacuterio",
            dataIndex : 'valorUnitario',
            flex : 1,
            align : 'right',
            menuDisabled : true,
            editor : {
                xtype : 'numberfield',
                allowBlank : false,
                minValue : 0,
                forcePrecision : true,
                decimalSeperator : ','
            },
            renderer : Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0.000,00')
           }
```

Comment: You have typo in your numberfield config. The config property is decimalSeparator not decimalSeperator http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number-cfg-decimalSeparator

Comment: Thank you Akatum, it was a typo, sorry my mistake. Now is working perfectly

Answer (score -1):

it was a typo, sorry my mistake. Now is working perfectly

Comment: You should have just updated the question instead of this. Or might as well deleted it completely.